# Write to a program's standard input using a shell script

Tags: java, bash, unix

I want to send text input to the following Java program from the Unix (bash) command line, so that it will print the text that was entered. How can I write a shell script that will send the string "Print this" to the Java program?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReadStuff{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter some text:");
        System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: If your program takes input only from the command line, then you can follow this way: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: Would I need to modify the program (as it currently exists on this page) in order to get it to work?

Answer (score 6):

Use `echo`

```
echo "Print this" | java ReadStuff
```

Note that this will output:

```
Enter some text:
Print
```

Because you are calling `Scanner.next()` which reads the next word, not the entire line.

Or alternatively, if you have stuff in a file:

```
cat file_with_Print_this | java ReadStuff
```

Comment: I meant to write `Scanner.nextLine()`.

Comment: Now what should I do if I want two programs to read each other's input?

Comment: or Expect -- [this example](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/expect/expect-1/expect/example/chess.exp) has a chess program playing against itself.